# Need to get the output in the same page (using django model forms with ajax)

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I've tried to reinvent a situation, I've faced recently with a simple example, as follows:

I'm new to using ajax with django and this is what I'm trying to do..

I have a single page ('home') and there are two buttons Form1 and Form2; clicking either one of the buttons executes an ajax call and    gets it's corresponding form without refreshing (I'm able to pass a    get request properly using jquery function with ajax call to display    it on the 'home' page itself, without refreshing). It looks like    this:

[image]

Each of those select fields are pre-populated with django model values thorugh `Model.object.create(name=name)` in the IDLE, and have only one field(besides the pk id).

If I select a value from either of both dropdowns and hit process, it should display the length of the selected string, without refreshing the page (just as how the page doesn't refresh while switching the forms) **---->** This is where I'm exactly struck and I know the approach I'm using is wrong, but not sure on how to correct it.

Can someone please help me in completing the intended purpose of this django app.

Sorry for the pasted length of the whole code; for helpers' convenience I uploaded the folder to github as a public repository: https://github.com/kiran0819/questions/tree/master/demo

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from ajax_demo import views as ajax_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', ajax_views.home, name='home'),
    path('view1/', ajax_views.view1, name='view1'),
    path('view2/', ajax_views.view2, name='view2')
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db.models import Model, CharField


class Model1(Model):
    name1 = CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name1


class Model2(Model):
    name2 = CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name2
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, ModelChoiceField
from .models import Model1, Model2


class Form1(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ['name1']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name1'] = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model1.objects.all())


class Form2(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = ['name2']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name2'] = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model2.objects.all())
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import Form1, Form2
from .controllers import get_length


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'ajax_demo/home.html')


def view1(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Form1(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            selected_name = form.cleaned_data.get('name1')  # WROTE THESE JUST FOR TESTING ON PYTHON CONSOLE
            print(get_length(selected_name))  # WROTE THESE JUST FOR TESTING ON PYTHON CONSOLE
    else:
        form = Form1()
    return render(request, 'ajax_demo/template1.html', {'form': form})


def view2(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Form2(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            selected_name = form.cleaned_data.get('name2')   # WROTE THESE JUST FOR TESTING ON PYTHON CONSOLE
            print(get_length(selected_name))   # WROTE THESE JUST FOR TESTING ON PYTHON CONSOLE
    else:
        form = Form2()
    return render(request, 'ajax_demo/template2.html', {'form': form})
```

**controllers.py**

```
def get_length(name):
    return len(str(name))
```

**template1.html**

```
<form method="POST" id="form1" action="{% url 'view1' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        {{ form }}
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Process</button>
</form>
```

**template2.html**

```
<form method="POST" id="form2" action="{% url 'view2' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        {{ form }}
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Process</button>
</form>
```

**home.html**

Here I have included the html comment where I want to display the selected string length. And also a js comment, on not knowing how to write the jquery functions.

```
{% extends 'ajax_demo/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <button id="load_form1">Form 1</button>
    <button id="load_form2">Form 2</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="form_space" style="display:none;"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="output_string_length" style="display:none; ">
        <!-- Here's where I want to get the length of the output(length of the selected string)-->
        <!-- without refreshing the page -->
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block js %}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){

        $(function getForm1(){
            $("#load_form1").click(function (){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/view1/",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: $("#form1").serialize(),
                    success: function (data){
                        $("#form_space").html(data);
                        $("#form_space").fadeIn("slow");
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        $(function getForm2(){
            $("#load_form2").click(function (){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/view2/",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: $("#form2").serialize(),
                    success: function (data){
                        $("#form_space").html(data);
                        $("#form_space").fadeIn("slow");
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        // [WHAT DO I WRITE HERE TO BE ABLE TO GET THE LENGTH OF THE SELECTED STRING]
    });
</script>
{% endblock js %}
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
    {% block js %}
    {% endblock js %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: using `HttpResponse(get_length(selected_name))`, I'm able to get the result in a different url `('view1/' or 'view2/')`, but still cannot figure out how to get it on the home page element `div with id ("#output_string length")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to write another view for response

```
def view1_response(request):
    name = request.POST.get('selected_name')
    length = get_length(name)
    return render(request, 'ajax_demo/template_response1.html', {'length': length})
```

Render the context to a different template (template_response1.html)

```
    <div id="template1_output">
        {{ length }}
    </div>
```

And the ajax beneath the form elements:

```
<form method="POST" id="form1" action="{% url 'view1' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        {{ form }}
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" id="submit1">Process</button>
</form>
<script>
    $(function (){
        $("#id_name1").change(function (){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}" }
            });
            $("#submit1").click(function (){
                var selectedName = $("#id_name1 option:selected").text();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{% url 'view1_response' %}",
                    data: {
                        selected_name: selectedName
                    },
                    success: function (data){
                        $("#output").empty();
                        $("#output").html(data);
                        $("#output").fadeIn();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Same goes for Form2